# C++ Using find on a list of objects

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, find

I can not seem to get std::find to work with a std::list of objects.  I get the error "**no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘Rabbit’ and ‘const int’)** ". Fairly sure I need to utilize an object iterator and a lambda function,  I'm just completely lost on how to do so and I just need some guidance. What I am ultimately trying to do is to iterator to a specific location in the list and pull the color string from that object in the list. 
Edited to clarify the question and simplify the code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <list>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include "Rabbit.h"
    #include "Population.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        Population Tracker;
        Tracker.parentSeed(); //generate first random 8, and populate the list
        Tracker.Breed(); //generate children, not working nothing happening  as   getMother does not work
        return 0;
    }

    class Rabbit
    {
        protected:
            const std::vector<std::string> namesList
            {"Maxwell", "David", "Laura", "Sarah" , "Benjamin", "Carl",
             "Rick", "Maggie", "Glenn", "Daryl", "Michonne", "Roseita",
             "Leslie", "Randy", "Ethan", "Survan", "Leah", "Tisha", "Marcus"};

            const std::vector<std::string> colorList
            {"Red", "Green", "Blue",
             "Grey", "Tan", "Brown",
             "Calico", "White"};

        public:
            Rabbit(); //blank for the initial population
            Rabbit(int); // pass an int for color inherited from mother
            ~Rabbit();
            void getRabbit();
            void randomNumGen(int);
            std::string name;
            std::string color;
    };

    Rabbit::Rabbit()
    {
        std::random_device random; //random seed obj
        std::default_random_engine e1(random()); //get a random number seed
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> name_dist(0, 17); // vector position of name
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> color_dist(0, 7); // vector position of col
     color = colorList[color_dist(e1)];
     name = nameList[name_dist(e1)];
    }

    class Population
    {
        friend class Rabbbit;
        protected:

        public:
            Population();

            void popStats(int, bool);
            void popList(Rabbit);
            int getMother();
            void parentSeed(); // generate initial population.  All stats are random.
            std::list<Rabbit> femaleList;
            std::list<Rabbit> maleList;
            std::list<Rabbit>::iterator male_it;
            std::list<Rabbit>::iterator female_it;
    };

    int Population::getMother()
    {
       female_it++
       //do something to iterate list and get data from the object at that position.  Not to be sequential, just used that as example. 
    }

    void Population::Breed()
    {
        /*
            generate a new rabbit with color inhereited from the mother
            father does not matter as all other stats are random
        */
        if(maleList.size() > 2 && femaleList.size() > 2)
        {
            getMother(); // does nothing right now
            std::cout << "Breed Success!" << std::endl;
            Rabbit newRabbit;
            popList(newRabbit);
        }
    }

void Population::parentSeed()
{
    /*
        Generate the initial seed count
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        Rabbit newRabbit;
        popList(newRabbit);
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) Please reduce the code to a single example that *can be compiled* as is. (2) What do you *mean* by trying to `std::find` a `Rabbit` with "position" 1? (3) Note that you allocate rabbits dynamically but never deallocate, so there is a memory leak; the dynamic allocation, use of `new`, is not necessary.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I edited the question and code for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is not aware of how it should distinguish between your `Rabbit`s and raw integers. Thus, it's telling that you need to show it how to distinguish between them by defining an overloaded equality operator for your `Rabbit` objects and integers. You should add the following overloaded operators to your code:

```
bool
operator==(int const &i, Rabbit const &r) {
  ...
  return ?;
}

bool
operator==(Rabbit const &r, int const &i) {
  ...
  return ?;
}
```